# How do I get Keycloak to connect to MySQL DB?

Tags: mysql, keycloak

I've been crawling a number of sites like [this](https://sunitkatkar.blogspot.com/2020/07/setting-up-keycloak-10-with-mysql-8-on.html) trying to get Keycloak working with a MySQL persistence layer.  I am using docker, but I'm using my own images so it pulls passwords and other sensitive data from a secrets manager instead of environment variables or Docker secrets.  The images are pretty close to stock besides that however.

Anyway, I have a MySQL 8 container up and running, and from within the Keycloak 12.0.3 container I can connect to the MySQL container fine:

```
# mysql -h mysql -u keycloak --password=somethingtochangelater -D keycloak -e "SHOW DATABASES;"
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| keycloak           |
+--------------------+
```

So there's no problems of connectivity between the instances, and that username/password has access to the `keycloak` database fine.

So then I ran several commands to configure the Keycloak instance (keycloak is installed at `/opt/myco/bin/keycloak`):

```
/opt/myco/bin/keycloak/bin/standalone.sh &

# Pausing for server startup
sleep 20

# Add mysql module - JDBC driver unpacked at /opt/myco/bin/keycloak-install/mysql-connector-java-8.0.23/mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar
/opt/myco/bin/keycloak/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --command="module add --name=com.mysql --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api --resources=/opt/myco/bin/keycloak-install/mysql-connector-java-8.0.23/mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar --module-root-dir=/opt/myco/bin/keycloak/modules/system/layers/keycloak/"

# Removing h2 datasource
/opt/myco/bin/keycloak/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --command="/subsystem=datasources/data-source=KeycloakDS:remove"

# Adding MySQL datasource
/opt/myco/bin/keycloak/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --command="/subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=mysql:add(driver-name=mysql,driver-module-name=com.mysql,driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver)"

# TODO - add connection pooling options here...
# Configuring data source
/opt/myco/bin/keycloak/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --command="data-source add --name=KeycloakDS --jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS --enabled=true --password=somethingtochangelater --user-name=keycloak --driver-name=com.mysql --use-java-context=true --connection-url=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/keycloak?useSSL=false&characterEncoding=UTF-8"

# Testing connection
/opt/myco/bin/keycloak/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --command="/subsystem=datasources/data-source=KeycloakDS:test-connection-in-pool"

# Creating admin user
/opt/myco/bin/keycloak/bin/add-user-keycloak.sh -r master -u "admin" -p "somethingelse"

# Shutting down initial server
/opt/myco/bin/keycloak/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect command=":shutdown"
```

This all appears to run fine.  Note especially the `test-connection-in-pool` has no problems:

```
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => [true],
    "response-headers" => {"process-state" => "reload-required"}
}
```

However, when I go to start the server back up again, it crashes with several exceptions, starting with:

```
22:31:52,484 FATAL [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) Error during startup: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to connect to database
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@12.0.3//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.getConnection(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:377)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@12.0.3//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.LiquibaseDBLockProvider.lazyInit(LiquibaseDBLockProvider.java:65)
...
```

it keeps going, though I suspect that Exception ultimately to be fatal, and it eventually dies with:

```
22:31:53,114 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 40) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractAddStepHandler$1@33063168 for operation add at address [
    ("subsystem" => "jca"),
    ("workmanager" => "default"),
    ("short-running-threads" => "default")
] failed -- java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.RejectingExecutor.execute(RejectingExecutor.java:37)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.rejectShutdown(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2029)
...
```

The module at `/opt/myco/bin/keycloak/modules/system/layers/keycloak/com/mysql/main` has the jar file and module.xml:

```
# ls
module.xml  mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar
# cat module.xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.mysql">

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
```

The standalone.xml file looks reasonable to me:

```
...
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:6.0">
            <datasources>
...
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS" pool-name="KeycloakDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/keycloak?useSSL=false&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8</connection-url>
                    <driver>com.mysql</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>keycloak</user-name>
                        <password>somethingtochangelater</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                    <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                        <driver-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
...
```

So.... anyone have any idea what's going on?  What else do I need to do to get Keycloak talking properly to MySQL?  Anything else I can do to debug what the issue is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what is wrong with your particular case, but I used jboss/ keycloak image and it connects to MySQL just fine. Maybe you can derive your custom image from there.  The full setup in my blog post https://link.medium.com/eK6IRducpeb

Comment: Your blog page is good, although FWIW I think you're supposed to copy the relevant parts of the link into the answer here in case that web page ever goes away.

It doesn't fully answer my question either, as I don't really want the stock jboss image, because I want to be able to wait for / initialize the DB within the container, as well as pull passwords and such from a non-Docker secrets manager.  The jboss image is (justifiably) pretty crippled in terms of extending (e.g. no yum).

However I am accepting this as the answer because it does work.

Comment: I used a multi-stage build to copy what I needed into the image I extended from the jboss image, and then wrapped the entrypoint script (/opt/jboss/tools/docker-entrypoint.sh) in order to obtain the secrets I needed.  Not exactly how I want to do it, but it works.

Comment: For others that wind up here and want to use the jboss image, the env var I was missing was DB_VENDOR.  You'll want to set DB_VENDOR, DB_ADDR, DB_PORT, DB_DATABASE, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, KEYCLOAK_USER and KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD.